# How to merge .sql files listed in a .txt into a single .sql script using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've searched high and low for a solution to this problem but have so far drawn a blank. I'm fairly new to batch scripts, so apologies if this turns out to be a stupid question.

I have a list of sql filenames in a .txt file which I would like to merge into a single sql script. The .txt file and the .bat file are in one subdirectory of a root location, and the sql scripts are in a separate subdirectory like so:

- root\

  - batch files\

    - .bat
    - .txt
  - views\

    - .sql

I can read the file names out the .txt file quite happily and pass them to a subroutine using this:

```
for /f %%d in (IncludeList.txt) do call :Include_List "%%d"
goto :eof
```

The part that is causing me problems is the :Include_List subroutine. I need to be able to search the `views\` subdirectory for each specified filename and then copy the content of it into a new script.

I tried the following, which I think is the nearest I've got it to working, without it actually working:

```
:Include_List
for /r %%f in ('DIR /B /S ..\Views\vw*.sql ^| find /i %~1') do type %%f >> _All_views.sql
```

It seems to be treating each part of this `('DIR /B /S ..\Views\vw*.sql ^| find /i %~1')` as a filename and then failing to find any of them. It's also checking inside the `batch files\` directory and not the `views\` directory.

One additional requirement, is that this is part of a larger batch file, which would need to continue processing after the files had been looped through and written to the newly created `_all_views.sql` file.

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible with a batch file? Or am I just going to have to manually add each required file into the batch file like this

```
type ..\Views\[filename].sql >> _All_views.sql
```

Comment: Try `for /f "delims="` (parsing by lines) instead of `for /r` (recursive file lookup).

Comment: Excellent, that is exactly what I was after! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on wOxxOm's answer my final solution is as follows:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%d in (IncludeList.txt) do ( 
 for /f "delims=" %%f in ('DIR /B /S ..\Views\vw*.sql ^| find /i "%%d"') do type %%f >> _All_views.sql
)
```

I did away with the subroutine as it was causing issues when placed inside a larger batch file, but a nested `for` loop works perfectly for what I need.